# Strange bash behavior when expanding ${*:0:80}

Tags: bash, syntax

When expanding ${*:0:80} which should display the 1st chars of $1-$n, bash will prepend $0 and won't honor the 80 size limit.

Even wired, if I do some shift, $0 is still displayed while, shifted element have disappeared.

le say we create the /tmp/test.sh (chmod +x /tmp/test.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

A=$1
shift
B=$2
shift
C="$*"
echo "test1: ${*:0:80}"
echo "test2: ${C:0:80}"
```

When running it on CentOS-7.6.1810 bash (bash-4.2.46-31.el7.x86_64), here is the strange output: (test1 wrong ($0 printed and message not truncated to 80 chars), test2 ok)

```
/tmp/test.sh word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 word11 word12 word13 word14 word15 word16 word17 word18 word19 word20
test1: /tmp/test.sh word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 word11 word12 word13 word14 word15 word16 word17 word18 word19 word20
test2: word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 word11 word12 word13 word14 wor
```

When running it on MacOS Mojav 10.14.6 (version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)),
here is another strange output: (test1 still wrong (not truncated), test2 ok)

```
/tmp/test.sh word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 word11 word12 word13 word14 word15 word16 word17 word18 word19 word20
test1: word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 word11 word12 word13 word14 word15 word16 word17 word18 word19 word20
test2: word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 word11 word12 word13 word14 wor
```

IMHO, Expected result should be:

- $0 shouldn't be outputted
- output ($2-$n) should be truncated to 80 chars

Do I miss something or do I hit a bash bug or is this inconsistency across Oses expected?

Comment: *${\*:0:80} which should display the 1st chars of $1-$n,* where did you get this information?

Comment: `bash` doesn't define what `${*:...}` will do, only `${@:...}`, and *that* is defined to expand to a subset of the positional parameters, not a prefix of each one.

Comment: @chepner `${*:..:..}` will work just as array indexed by `[*]`: `foo(){ printf '{%s}\n' "${*:1:2}"; }; IFS=, foo 1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th` => `{1st,2nd}`.

Comment: @mosvy That's how it *appears* to work, but that is not documented behavior as far as I can tell.

Comment: @chepner in that case, they should document it ;-)

Comment: @mosvy It's also possible that it is *intentionally* undocumented, and one should not rely on whatever it currently does.

Comment: @chepner they're well capable of that. But even in the latest source code, they go through the same paths, and work the same (notice that `"${*:x:y}"` does not work identical to `"${@:x:y}"` when _quoted_, but they're both  consistent with their `"$*"`, `"$@"`, `"${arr[*]}"` and `"${arr[@]}"` equivalents.

Comment: @mosvy `bash` also still supports `$[...]`, despite it being officially deprecated since the late 90s and no longer even mentioned in the documentation. Just because something works doesn't mean you should *depend* on it to work, if it isn't documented.

Answer (score 1):

Substring expansion for `*` is not documented at all, though it is for `@`:

> If parameter is @, the result is length positional parameters beginning at offset.  A negative
>                 offset is taken relative to one greater than the greatest positional parameter, so  an  offset
>                 of  -1  evaluates to the last positional parameter.  It is an expansion error if length evalu-
>                 ates to a number less than zero.

That is, substring expansion selects a range of positional parameters (including, for some reason, the special parameter $0, probably to make indexing intuitive); it does not apply substring expansion to each parameter individually. The documentation has no mention of what happens if the parameter is `*` (though it explicitly defines the behavior of an array indexed by either `@` or `*`).

`${*:x:y}` does appear to behave identically to `${@:x:y}`, though it isn't clear whether this is an artifact of the implementation that could change or if there is an oversight in the documentation.

`zsh` does define `${*:0:80}` as the first 80 characters of the single string resulting from the concatenation of the positional parameters, for what it's worth.

Comment: Also, here's the bash4 changelog: "3. a. When using substring expansion on the positional parameters, a starting index of 0 now causes $0 to be prefixed to the list."

Comment: Thanks; I thought there was a change related to that, but I couldn't remember exactly what it was.

Comment: Regarding `${*:x:y}` vs. `${@:x:y}`: `"${*:x:y}"` is one string, whereas `"${@:x:y}"` is quoted per element, so `arr1=("${*:1:2}")` results in a one-element array, but `arr2=("${@:1:2}")` has two elements.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I suspect that's why `${*:...:...}` is not defined. With `${@...}`, you are always talking about a sequence of values; with `${*...}`, it's ambiguous (though again good practice dictates you use it quoted and only when you *want* a single joined string).

Answer (score 1):

In a `${var:off:len}` expansion form, if the `var` is `*` or `@`, the `off` and `len` will select a number of `len` positional parameters starting with index `off` instead of a substring of `var`:

```
foo(){
    printf '{%s}\n' "${*:2:2}"
    printf '[%s]\n' "${@:2:2}"
}
IFS=, foo 1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th

{2nd,3rd}
[2nd]
[3rd]
```

Notice the difference between `$*` when `$@` when **quoted**: the first will join the parameters into a single word with the first character of the `IFS` variable, the second will expand each parameter into a separate word.

This is consistent with how arrays indexed by `[*]` or `[@]` work, and is the same as in `ksh93` (where IIRC the `${var:off:len}` construct first appeared).

In the `bash` docs, this is **not documented for `$*`**, but only for `$@` and for the arrays indexed by `[*]` or `[@]`.

But the source code follows the same paths and diverge at the same points for `*` or `@`: so while it is perfectly possible that they may change it one day by adding a special case (maybe just out of spite ;-)), I find it highly unlikely.

For completion, this is a snippet from **`ksh93`**'s manpage, which describes this behavior:

> `${parameter:offset:length}`
>   `${parameter:offset}`
>   ...
>   If `parameter` is `*` or `@`, or is an array name indexed by `*` or `@`, then `offset` and `length`  refer to the array index and number of elements respectively.  A negative offset is taken relative to  one greater  than  the  highest  subscript  for indexed arrays. The order for associate arrays is unspecified.

---

This is very different in `zsh` (but even there, it is not inconsistent between positional parameters and arrays): when either `$*`, an array subscripted by `*` or a simple array name is used, all the elements will be first joined into a string, then the `${var:off:len}` will extract a substring from it:

```
$ zsh -c 'IFS=-; printf "{%s}\n" "${*:0:8}"' zsh-c foo bar baz
{foo-bar-}
$ zsh -c 'arr=(foo bar baz); IFS=-; printf "{%s}\n" "${arr[*]:0:8}"'
{foo-bar-}
```

---

In `bash`, if you want to join the positional arguments into a string, and extract a substring of it, use an intermediate variable:

```
foo(){ local IFS=' '; local s="$*"; printf '{%s}\n' "${s:3:8}"; }
foo 1st 2nd 3rd

{ 2nd 3rd}
```

Comment: For completeness, `mksh` and busybox `ash` are 2 other shells that now support `${var:offset:length}`. But in `mksh`, it's not supported for `*` nor `@` (at least in R57) and in busybox sh, the substring is applied to the concatenation for both `*` and `@` (but `@` splitting still somehow happens, where the separation between elements counts as one character in the offset/length calculation).